# PostgreSQL sum without aggregation

Tags: postgresql

I have one table:

```
a b
x 5
y 20
z 10
```

i want to have a sum of column b but without aggregation, thus i would get this as result:

```
a b  c
x 5  35
y 20 35
z 10 35
```

This should be possible right? How this the Select comming from the table above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions for that:

```
select a, b, sum(b) over () as c
from the_table
order by a
```